# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to number

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have totaled the amount of the production and the amount of sinistre now I want to divide the sinistre amount on production (s / p)

```
public function somsin(){
    $sumsin = DB::table('sinistres')
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(montant_sin) as totalsin'))
    ->get();
    $sumpro = DB::table('productions')
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(montant_pro) as montant_pro'))
    ->get();
    $toto = $sumsin[0]/$sumpro[0];
    return view('test')->with(['sumsin'=>$sumsin, 'sumpro'=>$sumpro, 'toto'=>$toto]);
}
```

Object of class stdClass could not be converted to number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a *single value* from the query it's better to use the `value()` function, i.e.:

```
public function somsin(){
    $sumsin = DB::table('sinistres')
        ->select(DB::raw('sum(montant_sin) as totalsin'))
        ->value('totalsin');
    $sumpro = DB::table('productions')
        ->select(DB::raw('sum(montant_pro) as montant_pro'))
        ->value('montant_pro');
    $toto = $sumsin/$sumpro;
    return view('test')->with(['sumsin'=>$sumsin, 'sumpro'=>$sumpro, 'toto'=>$toto]);
}
```

Or even better with an *aggregate* function like `sum()`:

```
public function somsin(){
    $sumsin = DB::table('sinistres')
        ->sum('montant_sin');
    $sumpro = DB::table('productions')
        ->sum('montant_pro');
    $toto = $sumsin/$sumpro;
    return view('test')->with(['sumsin'=>$sumsin, 'sumpro'=>$sumpro, 'toto'=>$toto]);
}
```

The error you have is because you are trying to sum two *standard objects*, the `get()` function returns an *array of standard objects*, you can also solve using this line *with your own queries*:

```
 $toto = $sumsin[0]->totalsin/$sumpro[0]->montant_pro;
```